# What is the efficient way to use apply method in column of pandas Dataframe for large dataset?

Tags: pandas, preprocessing, dataframe, colab

I have a dataset of approximate 1 hundred thousand records. I want to use apply method in each of the records for further data processing but it takes very long time to process (As apply method works linearly).
I have tried this in Google Colab by selecting GPU settings but still it is very slow. I also try "swifter.apply" but still it is not as efficient.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Please give an example of the data in one of the cells and the method you want to apply - this will affect the best way to get the job done. Also, how many are "1 lakh records"? :)

Comment: You can write your function with vectorization and get the output by giving the pandas columns. please tell us a little about data and function to get a better response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `pandarallel` it works very efficiently for parallel processing. You can find more information about it [here](https://github.com/nalepae/pandarallel).

You should not use this if your apply function is a lambda function. Now assuming you're trying to apply it on a DataFrame called `df`:

```
from pandarallel import pandarallel

pandarallel.initialize(nb_workers=n) #n is the number of worker used for parallelization, you can leave it blank and it will use all the cores

def foo(x):
   return #what ever you're trying to compute


df.parallel_apply(foo, axis=1) #if you're applying to multiple columns
df[column].parallel_apply(foo) # if its just one column
```

Another option you can try is using the python `multiprocessing` library, here you will break your dataframe into smaller chunks and run them together.

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import cpu_count, Parallel

cores = cpu_count() #Gets number of CPU cores on your machine
partitions = cores #Define number of partitions

def parallelize(df, func):
    df_split = np.array_split(df, partitions)
    pool = Pool(cores)
    df = pd.concat(pool.map(func, df_split))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return df
```

Now you can run this `parallelize` function on your `df`:

```
df = parallelize(df, foo)
```

The more number of cores you have the faster this will be!

Comment: Hi , Thankyou so much Its help me alot.

Comment: No problem @Sweety. If it worked out for you, it would be helpful if you could accept the answer so others might find it useful in the future as well!

Comment: Hi @Samarth , I wanted to know one more thing that... Wat would be more efficient to work on such multiprocessing things .. 4 cores 32GB or 8 cores 8GB as I have not so much idea about infra of setup . So on which platform should we proceed to get better results faster.(Faster I mean taking less time).